# Rmagick Failed Installation

Tags: ruby, rubygems, imagemagick, rmagick

Having problem installing rmagick gem on my Mac.  All my software is up to date.  This is my error message.  I've tried reinstalling ImageMagick, but nothing seems to work.  I use homebrew - that couldn't because this issue, right?

I'm a bit of a command line novice, so perhaps this is an easy fix, but I do not understand this error message.

```
Devens-MacBook-Air:~ Deven$ gem install rmagick  
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...  
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:  
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rmagick-      2.15.4/ext/RMagick
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160416-51851-5yrwrn.rb               extconf.rb  
checking for clang... yes  
checking for Magick-config... yes  
checking for outdated ImageMagick version (<= 6.4.9)... no  
/usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 41: pkg-config: command not found  
/usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 47: pkg-config: command not found  
/usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 50: pkg-config: command not found  
/usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 53: pkg-config: command not found  
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes  
/usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 53: pkg-config: command not found  
Can't install RMagick 2.15.4. Can't find the ImageMagick library or one of the dependent libraries. Check the mkmf.log file for more detailed information.  

*** extconf.rb failed ***  
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.  

Provided configuration options:  
-with-opt-dir  
-with-opt-include  
-without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include  
-with-opt-lib  
-without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib  
-with-make-prog  
--without-make-prog  
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0/rmagick-2.15.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rmagick-2.15.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0/rmagick-2.15.4/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 3):

All the following command lines will figure out this issue.

```
brew install imagemagick
cd /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/lib
ln -s libMagick++-Q16.7.dylib   libMagick++.dylib
ln -s libMagickCore-Q16.7.dylib libMagickCore.dylib
ln -s libMagickWand-Q16.7.dylib libMagickWand.dylib
gem install rmagick
```

6.8.0 is imagemagick version here. Hoping this will work.